# DesiredCapabilities.android() is throwing an error "The method android() is undefined for the type DesiredCapabilities"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium4

DesiredCapabilities.android() is throwing an error "The method android() is undefined for the type DesiredCapabilities"

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android(); 
  
capabilities.setCapability("proxy", proxy);
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", android_deviceName);
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", mob_platformName);
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", android_platformVersion);
```

Should we replace DesiredCapabilities as below

```
MutableCapabilities caps = new MutableCapabilities();
```

Also getting the error as "The method iphone() is undefined for the type DesiredCapabilities"

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.iphone();
```